How to make my ggplot2 line graph, that contains alternating color segments, not have small gaps at the bends?
My goal is to make a professional looking line graph in R with ggplot2.
My line graph has alternating colors based on the value in data$color. However, the line looks like blocky rectangular segments. The line has a blocky and fragmented overall shape. How can I revise the plot to retain the color segments and have smooth continuous junctions?
Below is the code for a simplified example and the plot it produces.
data <- data.frame(
  x = 1:15,
  y = round(c(0.0146,0.0025,0.0647,0.0311,-0.0177,-0.0487,-0.022,0.0892,0.0442,0.0159,0.0517,0.031,-0.0416,0.048,0.0347), digits = 2)
)

data$color <- "green"
data$color[8:12] <- "blue"

my_plot <- ggplot(data, aes(x = x)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = y, color = color, group = 1), size = 1) +
  scale_colour_identity()

ggsave("test_green_blue.png", plot = my_plot, bg = "white", width = 10, height = 4)


And below is a closeup:

Below is an example of the smooth continuous appearance I am looking for.
data <- data.frame(
  x = 1:15,
  y = round(c(0.0146,0.0025,0.0647,0.0311,-0.0177,-0.0487,-0.022,0.0892,0.0442,0.0159,0.0517,0.031,-0.0416,0.048,0.0347), digits = 2)
)

my_plot <- ggplot(data, aes(x = x)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = y), size = 1)

ggsave("test_default.png", plot = my_plot, bg = "white", width = 10, height = 4)



Edit 1 Aug. 30, 2024
@michiel-duvekot provided a smooth answer of adding the argument
lineend = "round"

to geom_line()
This looks like it solves the problem of the blocky junctions! Thank you Michiel.
However, my specific case is seeking to draw a horizontal line and have the alternative colored segments only begin below the line. The "round" lineend is breaching the horizontal line (i.e. it's extending past the specific coordinates of the point where the line should end). If anyone has a solution for a smooth line that also has the colors not exceed their datapoint coordinates, that would solve my use case and I would greatly appreciate it.
See below for reproducible code and images from the created plot.
data <- data.frame(
  x = 1:15,
  y = round(c(0.0146,0.0025,0.0647,0.0311,0,-0.0487,0,0.0892,0.0442,0.0159,0.0517,0.031,-0.0416,0.048,0.0347), digits = 2)
)

data$color <- "green"
data$color[5:6] <- "blue"

my_plot <- ggplot(data, aes(x = x)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = y, color = color, group = 1), size = 1, lineend = "round") +
  scale_colour_identity() +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0, size = 0.5)

my_plot
ggsave("test_green_blue_round_v1.1.png", plot = my_plot, bg = "white")




Use the lineend argumment of geom_line()
lineend = "round"


Thank you Michiel for your answer. That solved the continuous line along the junctions!
I added an edit requesting if there's a solution that could also prevent the colors of the lines from breaching through the y-intercept line.

There are other args for geom_line() that look like they might be helpful, like linemitre, but TBH, I've never gotten those to work.
